# How to know available icon names in nuget mahapps metro icon package?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, nuget, mahapps.metro

I am using mahapp metro icon package in nuget to make a wpf application in C#. I am making a button icon as follows. I am using `appbar_arrow_right` icon. How can I know all the available icon names which I can use ?

`VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{StaticResource appbar_arrow_right}"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can see all the icons in file `Icons.xaml` under folder `Resources` in your project.

[image]

Comment: You can also download [Kaxaml](http://www.kaxaml.com/) (presumably Blend will work as well) to view the image directly.  I ended up doing this since the link provided by user3693167 was broken for me today (outstanding link otherwise) and the set at Barth Development doesn't exactly match the icons in my Icons.xaml.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the available icons [here](http://doan-hk5-cnpm04.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/NMCNPM/HKBookSoft_App/MahApps.Metro/Resources/light/) also

Comment: site no longer exists :(

Answer (score 1):

At [Barth Development](http://www.barth-dev.de/misc/stack/mahapps-icons-list/) you can see all icons along with their names.

Answer (score -1):

For people who need to see the icons, they are just ripped from [here](http://modernuiicons.com/)

Comment: site no longer exists